# Can I set workloads in mxnet when using a distributed environment (multi nodes)?

Tags: mxnet

I want to ask whether I can set different workloads when I use distributed computing environment using mxnet. I read some tutorial for distributed GPUs.

But I want to use distributed nodes (CPUs) environment and I want to set different workload to them. Can I do that? If yes, then can I get some examples about it?

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supported. Check this link which shows that you can specify work_load_list according to GPUs or CPUs you want to distribute your work load. 
http://mxnet.io/how_to/multi_devices.html#advanced-usage

Also, you should check python API reference (http://mxnet.io/api/python/model.html#mxnet.model.FeedForward). work_load_list parameter can be set while doing model.Feedforward.fit(__)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try it :)